# What is the difference of these POST commands?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference of these, and how do I know when to use which?

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
    // do something here on success
}, 'json');

$.post($(this).prop('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
    // do something here on success
}, 'json');

$.post($(this).closest("form").prop('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
    // do something here on success
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and second are identical, in this case. These functions has to be called from a form event handler. Instead of `$(this).prop/attr()`, `$(this)[0].action` and `this.action` can also be used.

The third method looks for the nearest form element, and retrieve the `action` attribute of the form. This method would be useful from a non-form context, e.g. from a `button` element.

Answer (score 1):

The first and second would be appropriate for a "submit" event handler associated with a `<form>` element. The second is probably better, but in actual use they're almost the same.

The third would be useful as a "click" handler on a `<button>` inside a `<form>`, or some similar situation.